# FFMPEG - Reduce speed / framerate of resulting video?

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I'm using this commnand in order to convert a set of JPGs into a video. The code works but the resulting video is too fast

```
exec('ffmpeg -y -f image2 -i img%d.jpg video.mpg 2>&1 >/dev/null', $output, $exit_status);
```

I've tried to add -r 15 before the output file name but it didn't work.

Here what I've tried but didn't work :

```
 exec('ffmpeg -y -f image2 -i img%d.jpg -r 15 video.mpg 2>&1 >/dev/null', $output, $exit_status);
```

Any hints would be highly appreciated

Comment: How many frames per second are the input images? If 15, you may want to move `-r 15` before the input specifier; `ffmpeg -y -r 15 -f image2 -i img%d.jpg -r 30 video.mpg`

Comment: Yes, that fixed the problem. But suprisingly, if I use different values for 15 and 30 in your example. it doesn't work ? I need to show only 1 or 2 images per second